# Internal Server get 550 unknown user, when mailing to existing Exchange Mailbox

Tags: exchange, smtp

I was setting up a Server and set up a ssmtp service for the application to send Mails to our people. It works fine for everyone expect for one user I get the Error Message: 
550 unknown user

All the Mailboxes are in the set up in the same Exchange Server and I compared in the Exchange Admin Center this user to other users (which can receive the mail) and there is no setting difference.

Also I tried to send mails from other internal Webserver (Debian / Windows) and on each server is the same error for this exact user but works fine for any other user.

I know that we had to rename this user at somepoint, but I also went throught the whole AD settings and they also were the same to other users.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you send this user an email from OWA, does it go through correctly? OWA uses live information, rather than any cache within Outlook. OWA is always the first test.

If OWA works correctly, then the problem is outside Exchange. Depending on whether it applies to SMTP traffic or Outlook will give you an indication where the error is. If Outlook only, probably the OAB. If SMTP (so emailing from something outside Exchange) then it will be something else.

Comment: Its working through OWA as well it works through Outlook. She also gets E-Mail vom external. Just SMTP from a Server does not work, for example with ssmtp on linux. It may has to do something with the edited from field. But the strange thing is it works for every other user expect this one.

Comment: If it works through OWA and Outlook, and gets email from external senders then the issue is not with Exchange. The problem will be either something between Exchange and the server you are using, or the server that is sending the email itself.

Comment: Thanks I managed to solve it. Due to your answer I figured out that we have a second mailserver which I didnt know of. And this smtp tried to send over this one and there the user didnt exist. My Bad. Thanks for your help!